# macos catalina bash shell not saving history

Tags: macos

Last night I went into my bash shell in terminal and entered a few commands.  Then today I go in but theyre not saved in the history (arrow up).  However the really old commands I used about 5 or more months ago are there, so the history is not empty.

Why is my history no longer activated and how do I activate it?

Answer (score 4):

macOS Catalina uses `zsh` as your shell, so your shell settings go to `~/.zshrc`

**Edit your settings**:

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

**Add these lines to your `~/.zshrc` file:**

```
HISTSIZE=100000
HISTFILESIZE=999999
SAVEHIST=$HISTSIZE
```

The `history`command in `zsh`also shows only 16 most recent lines from the history file unless you give it the start line as a parameter:

```
history 0
```

This will show you the whole history.

You can make an alias for this, so that the `history` command without the parameter will show the complete history as well:

**Add this line to your `~/.zshrc` file:**

```
alias history="history 0"
```

Comment: Thank you! I had set and unset many different zsh history related options to determine why I was unable to see my history. Using alias history="history 0" fixed all my issues.

Answer (score 1):

I switched from zsh to bash in OSX Catalina but the shell history wasn't saving. I had success fixing that by creating the ~/.bash_profile file and putting this inside:

```
export SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY=0
```

Got the idea from this older thread: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218731/why-bash-history-on-my-mac-wont-save

Answer (score 0):

Since macOS Catalina Apple's default shell is no longer bash, but [zsh](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsh).
Therefore your sources will no longer come from your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.

If you want to bash to be your default shell follow this steps:

System Preferences > Users and groups > right click on your user and select advance options. > On the Login Shell drop down menu select your prefered shell.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It does appear as bin/bash/.  I mean I do get the bash shell.  Just not any recent history.  Only old history.

Comment: Try adding the following commands on your `.bashrc` to reconfigure the up arrow search history:
`bind '"\e[A": history-search-backward'`
`bind '"\e[B": history-search-forward'`

Comment: OK that looks like it would restore key bindings.  Just to be clear, the keys work and cycle through the history just fine.  It's just the old history but nothing new as of yesterday gets saved.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem for myself as follow:

1. Check which shell is running: `echo $SHELL`
   It should return /bin/bash. Otherwise my solution not applied.
2. Backup .bash_profile with: `mv .bash_profile .bash_profile.bak`
3. Close your shell with `CMD + w`.
4. Reopen Terminal to check if bash history works, by typing some commands, then using `arrow up` to check
5. If terminal history seems to work again. Then the cause of the error lays down in the .bash_profile. If you want to keep your .bash_profile, you should comment out each of the command in there, to find out which commands cause the problem with the Terminal history.

In my case, the cause was commands of my working place related to cloud tooling.

I hope to help someone out!
Best